# Pass Bitmap object to unmanaged code

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged, managed

I have the following function in C++ managed (ref) class:

```
public static void Transform(Bitmap^ img);
```

I want to call it from C# managed code. What I do is this:

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(100, 100);
MyClass.Transform(image);
```

Is this correct, or do I need to use fixed statement? If so, then how?

Thank you.

Comment: voted for close due to duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661016/how-can-i-pass-a-net-bitmap-to-a-native-dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lock the bitmap's backing memory as [shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx).