# Pass bitmap from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++

How can I pass a Bitmap object which is loaded from C# to C++ native code, actually I'm working on wrapping some OpenCV API to be used from C#
But I faced a problem in passing the bitmap from c# and reconstruct it on c++

any code or idea would be appreciated

Comment: This has been asked and answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661016/how-can-i-pass-a-net-bitmap-to-a-native-dll?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LockBits` method to lock the `Bitmap` pixels in memory, and pass the pointer to the first pixel, the dimensions and the stride to C++ using a P/Invoke call.

Overview of `LockBits`: https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx

After the native code has finished processing the image, you would then free the lock using `UnlockBits`.

Comment: But passing the Scan0 to c++ will pass the point to the bits of the picture without the plate of the color

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .NET Bitmap object you can use the function [GetHBitmap()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4.aspx) to get a pointer to the image acessible from unmanaged code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing your own wrapper, you can use [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).