# Passing bitmap from c# to c++

Tags: c#, opencv, bitmap, c++-cli, pinvoke

I have an image processing function written in C++ based on opencv. In my wpf application I have used AForge library to access a webcam and update it on UI. This the function for handling newframes.

```
void UI_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmapFrame = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bitmapFrame.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            BitmapImage bitmapImageFrame = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImageFrame.BeginInit();
            bitmapImageFrame.StreamSource = ms;
            bitmapImageFrame.EndInit();
            bitmapImageFrame.Freeze();
            CurrentFrame = bitmapImageFrame;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("fatal::" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This my c++ code:

```
void FaceTracker(unsigned char* imageBuffer, int width, int height){    
   Mat frame(Size(width, height), CV_8UC4, imageBuffer, Mat::AUTO_STEP);
   Mat gray;
   cvtColor(frame, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
   //do more operations
}
```

I have two options. I have already found a code for copying data from `BitmapImage` to a `IntPtr` buffer using `CopyPixels`. I tested it and it works fine. But I also read I can simply pass a handle to the Bitmap using `GetHBitmap`. However this is not working for me. I read this [How can I pass a .NET Bitmap to a native DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661016/how-can-i-pass-a-net-bitmap-to-a-native-dll?rq=1) but I don't understand the part about `GetDIBits`. I also tried locking pixels of bitmap and passing like this:

```
bitmapFrame.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmapFrame.Width, bitmapFrame.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, 
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
NativeFunctions.FaceTracker(bitmapFrame.GetHbitmap(), bitmapFrame.Width, bitmapFrame.Height);
```

and simply passing HBitMap, neither works. I always get an exception stating memory access violation.

Comment: Just use `LockBits`, and pass `Scan0`.  `GetHbitmap` is not at all the same as `Scan0`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depends on the scope. If you can guarantee the bitmap isn't used elsewhere, you can lock the image buffer, and then pass the pointer down to the C++ code, and unlock it afterwards.

The **[LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** command returns a **[BitmapData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** class that has a pointer to the image buffer in its **[Scan0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.scan0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** property:

```
BitmapData bmpData = bitmapFrame.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmapFrame.Width, bitmapFrame.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, 
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

NativeFunctions.FaceTracker(bmpData.Scan0 , bitmapFrame.Width, bitmapFrame.Height);

bitmapFrame.UnlockBits(bmpData); //Remember to unlock!!!
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. As I had hoped, passing Bitmap instead of BitmapImage gave me a notable decrease in cpu use. Thank you :)

Comment: Dont forget to pass the `bmpData.Stride` as well. if you dont specify the step size in the C++ part, you will get distorted images (when dealing with color images) like this question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738718/getting-distorted-images-after-sending-them-from-c-sharp-to-opencv-in-c
Also you should be using `bitmapFrame..PixelFormat` instead of hard-coding it .

Comment: I was looking for days until I found this answer others need to upvote this one !!! It didn't give me the final solution but the data transfer is spot on :)

Answer (score 2):

An `HBITMAP` is an opaque handle to a bitmap. It is not a pixel buffer. So your two pieces of code do not match.

If you pass an `HBITMAP` to the native code then you need the native code to use GDI functions to obtain the pixel buffer and operate on it. Alternatively you could obtain a pixel buffer in your managed code and pass that to the native code. Whichever way you go you do need to match the two sides of the interop.

Comment: I am assuming `GetDIBits`, `CreateCompatibeDC` are GDI functions? I would prefer to convert my bitmap to pixel buffer and pass to native code. How would I do that?

Comment: LockBits and then Scan0

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Bitmap.Save()` method to convert it to a memory stream and then send it to `C++ dll`.

```
public Image ConvertImage(Image image)
{
   MemoryStream convertedImageMemoryStream;
   using (MemoryStream sourceImageStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
       image.Save(sourceImageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
       byte[] sourceImageData = sourceImageStream.ToArray();

       // Send it to dll and get the IntPtr byte array from dll

       byte[] imageData = new byte[imInfo.size];
       Marshal.Copy(imInfo.data, imageData, 0, imInfo.size);
       if (imInfo.data != IntPtr.Zero)
           AlgorithmCpp.ReleaseMemoryFromC(imInfo.data);
       convertedImageMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
    }
    Image processed = new Bitmap(convertedImageMemoryStream);
    return processed;
}
```

Then, in `C++ dll` use decoding such as `cv::imdecode()` method to get the image.

```
DllExport void convertToGray(unsigned char* data, int dataLen)
{
    vector<unsigned char> inputImageBytes(data, data + dataLen);
    Mat image = imdecode(inputImageBytes, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Mat processed;
    cvtColor(image, processed, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    vector<unsigned char> bytes;
    imencode(".png", processed, bytes);
    // ....
```

There are some pros in this way such as, 

`1. fewer data to transfer
2. minimum implementation effort from both C# and C++ end.
3. Does not depend on the source image type eg. color or grayscale or any other color palate type. So it's very safe to use.`

The only problem is that it is CPU intensive as there are an encoding and a decoding.

Details are [here](https://github.com/sumsuddin/ImageProcessingOpenCV).

Comment: Happy that it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use EmguCV. It is wrapper for openCV in C#. You dont have to worry about dll, lib etc. I can see that you want to track a face from webcamera. EmguCV gives you possibilty to capture webcamera image and later track face in very easy way: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Face_detection This link should help you also. Enjoy.

Comment: Yes I read about EmguCV. But the reason I am writing my own code is because I am a fresh out of college developer and my position requires me to work with interop a lot in the future. So I have to learn all its intricacies :)