# How do I send an image from C# to a DLL accepting OpenCV Mat properly?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, dll

I have a C++ class for which I created a C DLL to be used in our C# solution. Now I need to send images to the DLL, but I don't know the proper way of doing this. This is the C++ function signature:

```
std::vector<Prediction> Classify(const cv::Mat& img, int N = 2);
```

And this is how I went about it. Currently I tried to create this wrapper method in the DLL:

```
#ifdef CDLL2_EXPORTS
#define CDLL2_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CDLL2_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "../classification.h" 
extern "C"
{
    CDLL2_API void Classify_image(unsigned char* img_pointer, unsigned int height, unsigned int width, char* out_result, int* length_of_out_result, int top_n_results = 2);
    //...
}
```

Code in the dll:

```
CDLL2_API void Classify_image(unsigned char* img_pointer, unsigned int height, unsigned int width, char* out_result, int* length_of_out_result, int top_n_results)
    {
        auto classifier = reinterpret_cast<Classifier*>(GetHandle());
        cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_32FC3, (void*)img_pointer);

        std::vector<Prediction> result = classifier->Classify(img, top_n_results);

        //misc code...
        *length_of_out_result = ss.str().length();
    }
```

and in the `C#` code I wrote :

```
[DllImport(@"CDll2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void Classify_image(byte[] img, uint height, uint width, byte[] out_result, out int out_result_length, int top_n_results = 2);

private string Classify(Bitmap img, int top_n_results)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[200];
    int len;
    var img_byte = (byte[])(new ImageConverter()).ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));

    Classify_image(img_byte, (uint)img.Height, (uint)img.Width,res, out len, top_n_results);

    return  ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
}
```

but whenever I try to run the code, I get Access violation error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
> occurred in Classification Using dotNet.exe
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
> This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

and exception error says:

> {"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
> indication that other memory is corrupt."}

Deeper investigation into the code made it clear that, I get the exception error in this function:

```
void Classifier::Preprocess(const cv::Mat& img, std::vector<cv::Mat>* input_channels)
{
    /* Convert the input image to the input image format of the network. */
    cv::Mat sample;
    if (img.channels() == 3 && num_channels_ == 1)
        cv::cvtColor(img, sample, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    else if (img.channels() == 4 && num_channels_ == 1)
        cv::cvtColor(img, sample, cv::COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
    else if (img.channels() == 4 && num_channels_ == 3)
        cv::cvtColor(img, sample, cv::COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
    else if (img.channels() == 1 && num_channels_ == 3)
        cv::cvtColor(img, sample, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
    else
        sample = img;

    //resize image according to the input
    cv::Mat sample_resized;
    if (sample.size() != input_geometry_)
        cv::resize(sample, sample_resized, input_geometry_);
    else
        sample_resized = sample;

    cv::Mat sample_float;
    if (num_channels_ == 3)
        sample_resized.convertTo(sample_float, CV_32FC3);
    else
        sample_resized.convertTo(sample_float, CV_32FC1);

    cv::Mat sample_normalized;
    cv::subtract(sample_float, mean_, sample_normalized);

    /* This operation will write the separate BGR planes directly to the
    * input layer of the network because it is wrapped by the cv::Mat
    * objects in input_channels. */
    cv::split(sample_normalized, *input_channels);

    CHECK(reinterpret_cast<float*>(input_channels->at(0).data)
        == net_->input_blobs()[0]->cpu_data())
        << "Input channels are not wrapping the input layer of the network.";
}
```

The access violation occurs when it is attempted to resize the image meaning running this snippet:

```
//resize image according to the input
cv::Mat sample_resized;
if (sample.size() != input_geometry_)
    cv::resize(sample, sample_resized, input_geometry_);
```

Further investigation and debugging ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706018/cvresize-fails-with-access-violation-error-caused-by-struct-at-null/45718595#45718595)) made the culprit visible!
This approach proved to be plain wrong, or at the very least buggy. Using this code, the image on the `C++` side seemed to have been initialized properly, the number of channels, the height, and width all seemed fine.

But the moment you attempt to use the image, either by resizing it or even showing it using `imshow()`, it would crash the application and be giving an access violation exception, the very same error that happened when resizing and is posted in the question.

Looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706018/cvresize-fails-with-access-violation-error-caused-by-struct-at-null/45718595#45718595), I changed the C# code responsible for handing the image to the `dll`. the new code is as follows :

```
//Dll import 
[DllImport(@"CDll2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void Classify_Image(IntPtr img, uint height, uint width, byte[] out_result, out int out_result_length, int top_n_results = 2);

//...
//main code 

Bitmap img = new Bitmap(txtImagePath.Text);
BitmapData bmpData = img.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height),  ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,  PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
result = Classify_UsingImage(bmpData, 1);
img.UnlockBits(bmpData); //Remember to unlock!!!
```

and the C++ code in the DLL:

```
CDLL2_API void Classify_Image(unsigned char* img_pointer, unsigned int height, unsigned int width, char* out_result, int* length_of_out_result, int top_n_results)
    {
        auto classifier = reinterpret_cast<Classifier*>(GetHandle());

        cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3, (void*)img_pointer, Mat::AUTO_STEP);
    
        std::vector<Prediction> result = classifier->Classify(img, top_n_results);
        
        //...
        *length_of_out_result = ss.str().length();
    }
```

And doing so rectified all access violations I was getting previously.

Although I can now easily send images from C# to the DLL, I have some issue with the current implementation of mine. I don't know how to send the OpenCV type from C# to the needed function, currently I'm using a hardcoded image type as you can see, and this begs the question, what should I do when my input image is grayscale or even a png with 4 channels?

Comment: You shouldn't ask multiple questions in one post, also title has nothing to do with your question inside post: "but whenever I try to run the code, when it tries to convert the image into a byte array (...) I get Access violation error :" - looks like image converting problem. Maybe can you use some already working wrappers like EmguCV or opencvsharp to handle different pictures?

Comment: Thanks, but this is only one question not several ones, I asked how to do a specific action, I then explained what I have done and what was the result. 
either this is the correct way with a bug! or there is a better way of doing it. 
Either case, it has a unique answer that should address the issues concerning the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Trying many different approaches, I guess it would be beneficial to other people who seek to the the same thing, to know this. 
To cut a very long story short [(see this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45753429/resizing-the-image-in-c-sharp-and-sending-it-to-opencv-results-in-distorted-imag), The best way that I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45751685/2736559) (as @EdChum says it) :

> I'd pass the file as memory to your openCV dll, this should be able
>   to call imdecode which will sniff the file type, additionally you can
>   pass the flag

And also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45182245/2736559) to send a pointer to the `DLL` and there use `imdecode` to decode the image. This solved a lot of issues other approaches introduced. And will also save you alot of headaches.
Here is the code of intrest:
This is how my functions in the `DLL` and `C#` should have looked :

```
#ifdef CDLL2_EXPORTS
#define CDLL2_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CDLL2_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "classification.h" 
extern "C"
{
    CDLL2_API void Classify_Image(unsigned char* img_pointer, long data_len, char* out_result, int* length_of_out_result, int top_n_results = 2);
//...
}
```

The actual method :

```
CDLL2_API void Classify_Image(unsigned char* img_pointer, long data_len,
                              char* out_result, int* length_of_out_result, int top_n_results)
{
    auto classifier = reinterpret_cast<Classifier*>(GetHandle());
    vector<unsigned char> inputImageBytes(img_pointer, img_pointer + data_len);
    cv::Mat img = imdecode(inputImageBytes, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    cv::imshow("img just recieved from c#", img);

    std::vector<Prediction> result = classifier->Classify(img, top_n_results);
    //...
    *length_of_out_result = ss.str().length();
}
```

Here is the C# Dll Import:

```
[DllImport(@"CDll2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void Classify_Image(byte[] img, long data_len, byte[] out_result, out int out_result_length, int top_n_results = 2);
```

and This is the actual method sending the image back to the DLL:

```
private string Classify_UsingImage(Bitmap image, int top_n_results)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[200];
    int len;
    Bitmap img;

    if (chkResizeImageCShap.Checked)
        img = ResizeImage(image, int.Parse(txtWidth.Text), (int.Parse(txtHeight.Text)));
    else
        img = image;

    ImageFormat fmt = new ImageFormat(image.RawFormat.Guid);

    var imageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == image.RawFormat.Guid);
    //this is for situations, where the image is not read from disk, and is stored in the memort(e.g. image comes from a camera or snapshot)
    if (imageCodecInfo == null)
    {
        fmt = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
    }

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(ms,fmt);
        byte[] image_byte_array = ms.ToArray();
        Classify_Image(image_byte_array, ms.Length, result, out len, top_n_results);
    }

    return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
}
```

Comment: marvelous work! I can confirm that this still works three years later using a WPF app with a C++ dll using opencv 3.4.3