# Resizing the image in C# and sending it to OpenCV results in distorted image

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

This is a follow-up question related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738718/getting-distorted-images-after-sending-them-from-c-sharp-to-opencv-in-c). Basically, I have a DLL which uses OpenCV to do image manipulation. There are two methods, one accepting an `image-Path`, and the other one accepting a `cv::Mat`. The one working with `image-path` works fine. The one that accepts an `image` is problematic.

Here is the method which accepts the filename (DLL):

```
CDLL2_API void Classify(const char * img_path, char* out_result, int* length_of_out_result, int N)
{
    auto classifier = reinterpret_cast<Classifier*>(GetHandle());

    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(img_path);
    cv::imshow("img recieved from c#", img);
    std::vector<PredictionResults> result = classifier->Classify(std::string(img_path), N);
    std::string str_info = "";
    //...
    *length_of_out_result = ss.str().length();
}
```

Here is the method which accepts the image (DLL):

```
CDLL2_API void Classify_Image(unsigned char* img_pointer, unsigned int height, unsigned int width, 
                              int step, char* out_result, int* length_of_out_result, int top_n_results)
    {
        auto classifier = reinterpret_cast<Classifier*>(GetHandle());
        cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3, (void*)img_pointer, step);
        std::vector<Prediction> result = classifier->Classify(img, top_n_results);

        //...
        *length_of_out_result = ss.str().length();
    }
```

Here is the code in C# application: DllImport:

```
[DllImport(@"CDll2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        static extern void Classify_Image(IntPtr img, uint height, uint width, int step, byte[] out_result, out int out_result_length, int top_n_results = 2);
```

The method which sends the image to the DLL:

```
private string Classify_UsingImage(Bitmap img, int top_n_results)
{
    byte[] res = new byte[200];
    int len;
    BitmapData bmpData;
    bmpData = img.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, img.PixelFormat);
    Classify_Image(bmpData.Scan0, (uint)bmpData.Height, (uint)bmpData.Width, bmpData.Stride, res, out len, top_n_results);
    //Remember to unlock!!!
    img.UnlockBits(bmpData); 
    string s = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(res);
    return s;
}
```

Now, this works well when I send an image to the DLL. if I use `imshow()` to show the received image, the image is shown just fine.

**The Actual Problem:**

**However**, when I **resize** the very same image and send it using the very same method above, the image is distorted.

I need to add that, If I resize an image using the given C# method below, then save it, and then pass the filename to the `DLL` to be opened using `Classify(std::string(img_path), N);` it works perfectly.

Here is the screenshot showing an example of this happening:
Image sent from C` without being resized:

[image]

When The same image is first resized and then sent to the DLL:

[image]

Here the image is first resized (in C#), saved to the disk and then its `filepath` sent to the DLL:

[image]

This is the snippet responsible for resizing (C#):

```
/// <summary>
/// Resize the image to the specified width and height.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="image">The image to resize.</param>
/// <param name="width">The width to resize to.</param>
/// <param name="height">The height to resize to.</param>
/// <returns>The resized image.</returns>
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
{
    var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

    destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
    {
        graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
        {
            wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
            graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
        }
    }

    return destImage;
}
```

and this is the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jlGms.jpg)

This is the `Classify` method which uses the filepath to read the images:

```
std::vector<PredictionResults> Classifier::Classify(const std::string & img_path, int N)
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(img_path);
    cv::Mat resizedImage;
    std::vector<PredictionResults> results;
    std::vector<float> output;

   // cv::imshow((std::string("img classify by path") + type2str(img.type())), img);
    if (IsResizedEnabled())
    {
        ResizeImage(img, resizedImage);
        output = Predict(resizedImage);
    }
    else
    {
        output = Predict(img);
        img.release();
    }

    N = std::min<int>(labels_.size(), N);
    std::vector<int> maxN = Argmax(output, N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int idx = maxN[i];
        PredictionResults r;
        r.label = labels_[idx];
        r.accuracy = output[idx];
        results.push_back(r);
    }

    return results;
}
```

And this is the `ResizeImage` used in the method above :

```
void Classifier::ResizeImage(const cv::Mat & source_image, cv::Mat& resizedImage)
{
    Size size(GetResizeHeight(), GetResizeHeight());
    cv::resize(source_image, resizedImage, size);//resize image

    CHECK(!resizedImage.empty()) << "Unable to decode image ";
}
```

**Problem 2:**
Distortion after resizing aside, I am facing a discrepancy between resizing in C# and resizing using OpenCV itself.
I have created another method using EmguCV (also given below) and passed the needed information and did not face any such distortions which happen when we resize the image in C# and send it to the DLL.
**However**, this discrepancy made me want to understand what is causing these issues.
Here is the method which uses `EmguCV.Mat` is the code that works irrespective of resizing:

```
private string Classify_UsingMat(string imgpath, int top_n_results)
{
    byte[] res = new byte[200];
    int len;

    Emgu.CV.Mat img = new Emgu.CV.Mat(imgpath, ImreadModes.Color);

    if (chkResizeImageCShap.Checked)
    {
        CvInvoke.Resize(img, img, new Size(256, 256));
    }

    Classify_Image(img.DataPointer, (uint)img.Height, (uint)img.Width, img.Step, res, out len, top_n_results);

    string s = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(res);
    return s;
}
```

**Why do I care?**
Because, I get a different accuracy when I use OpenCV resize (both when I use EMguCV's `CvInvoke.resize()` and `cv::resize()`) than what I get from resizing the image in C#, saving it to disk and send the image path to the openCV.
So I either need to fix the distortion happening when I deal with images in C#, or I need to understand why the resizing in OpenCV has different results than the C# resizing.

So to summarize issues and points made so far:

1. All situations intact, If we resize the image inside C# application,
   and pass the info normally as we did before, the image will be
   distorted (example given above)
2. If we resize the image, save it to the disk, and give its filename
   to the OpenCV to create a new `cv::Mat`, it works perfectly without any issues.
3. If I use EmugCV and instead of working with `Bitmap`, use
   `Emug.CV.Mat` and send the needed parameters using mat object from
   C#, no distortion happens.

   **However**, the accuracy I get from a resized image from C# (see #2), is different than the one I get from the resized image using OpenCV.
   This doesn't make any difference if I resize the image before hand using 
   `CvInvoke.Resize()` from C#,  and send the resulting image to the DLL, 
   or send the original image (using EmguCV) and resizing it in the C++ code using `cv::resize()`. This is what prevents me from using the EmguCV or passing the image original image and resizing it inside the DLL using OpenCV.

Here are the images with different results, showing the issues:

```
--------------------No Resizing------------------------------
1.Using Bitmap-No Resize, =>safe, acc=580295
2.Using Emgu.Mat-No Resize =>safe, acc=0.580262
3.Using FilePath-No Resize, =>safe, acc=0.580262
--------------------Resize in C#------------------------------
4.Using Bitmap-CSharp Resize, =>unsafe, acc=0.770425
5.Using Emgu.Mat-EmguResize, =>unsafe, acc=758335
6.**Using FilePath-CSharp Resize, =>unsafe, acc=0.977649**
--------------------Resize in DLL------------------------------
7.Using Bitmap-DLL Resize, =>unsafe, acc=0.757484
8.Using Emgu.DLL Resize, =>unsafe, acc=0.758335
9.Using FilePath-DLL Resize, =>unsafe, acc=0.758335
```

I need to get the accuracy which I get at #6. as you can see the EmguCV resize and also the OpenCV resize function used in the DLL, act similar and don't work as expected (i.e. like #2)!, The C# resize method applied on the image is problematic, while if it is resized, saved and the filename passed, the result will be fine.

You can see the screen shots depicting different scenarios here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnMMu.jpg

Comment: Hello again, firstly what are the orig image sizes and the scaled image sizes? Are they retaining the same proportion wrt to imagexwidth proportions? Is the window size causing the distortion perhaps? If you specify a window size the same as the image size does it look correct?

Comment: @EdChum: Hi, images can have any sizes, this particular one, has HxW:`1263x893`. which needs to be resized to `256x256`.
the aspect ratio is not retained by the way. 
Do you mean to use `namedWindow()` prior to calling imshow?

Comment: I don't understand how that will work as the aspect ratio is going to squash the image, why not just resize to half/quarter? The hxw ratio is 1.41:1 you're trying to resize to ratio 1:1, why would this work without introducing some blanking space either side of the image so the image isn't distorted?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but our main classifier was trained on 256x256 images, therefore we need to resize all images to that size and the feed them to the classifier. 
By the way about setting the resolution explicitly, when bitmap is constructed using a filename, it automatically initializes the resolution.
I checked the values, they are `96x96`. I even checked the dpi for the case which we first resize the image , save it and then send its path to the DLL, its resolution was the same, `96x96`. but one is displayed correctly and the other not!

Comment: I also tried to use scale 1:1 by doing `cv::resize(source_image, resizedImage, size, 1, 1);//resize image` yet nothing changed!

Comment: What kind of classifier are you using? Normally one would use a classifier that is scale invariant such as SIFT/SURF/ORB etc.. so the image size shouldn't matter. I think I'd isolate the sizing issue as a separate thing for the moment and try to understand what is going wrong there, I think that forcing everything to be the same size seems wrong to me as you are introducing an aspect distortion which will affect the classifier as normally they would use some kind of angle, edge, distance metric on features

Comment: I'm using a deep CNN architecture (GoogleNet), those are feature extractors if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: I don't know what the requirements for that algorithm are but I would expect that it should be able to handle different sized image inputs, otherwise what I'd do is size one length to 256,  and for the other dimension where it doesn't fit, fill this with black so you get black bars either top + bottom or on the left/right side. Or pass a mask to the classifier so it ignores the regions outside the mask

Comment: @EdChum: Thats not the issue, CNN works pretty well in such situations. I agree we need to see what is going wrong. 
Could it be that openCV swaps RGB to BGR and that is making the difference here ? how can I see the statistics about an image in OpenCV?

Comment: by default openCV will load colour as BGR is my understanding so if you need RGB order then you need to specify this, this could be the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was to use `imdecode` [as EdChum suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45751685).
This is how the functions in the DLL and C# look now:

```
#ifdef CDLL2_EXPORTS
#define CDLL2_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CDLL2_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "classification.h" 
extern "C"
{
    CDLL2_API void Classify_Image(unsigned char* img_pointer, long data_len, char* out_result, int* length_of_out_result, int top_n_results = 2);
//...
}
```

The actual method:

```
CDLL2_API void Classify_Image(unsigned char* img_pointer, long data_len,
                              char* out_result, int* length_of_out_result, int top_n_results)
{
    auto classifier = reinterpret_cast<Classifier*>(GetHandle());
    vector<unsigned char> inputImageBytes(img_pointer, img_pointer + data_len);
    cv::Mat img = imdecode(inputImageBytes, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    cv::imshow("img just recieved from c#", img);

    std::vector<Prediction> result = classifier->Classify(img, top_n_results);
    //...
    *length_of_out_result = ss.str().length();
}
```

Here is the C# DllImport:

```
[DllImport(@"CDll2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void Classify_Image(byte[] img, long data_len, byte[] out_result, out int out_result_length, int top_n_results = 2);
```

and this is the actual method sending the image back to the DLL:

```
private string Classify_UsingImage(Bitmap image, int top_n_results)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[200];
    int len;
    Bitmap img;

    if (chkResizeImageCShap.Checked)
        img = ResizeImage(image, int.Parse(txtWidth.Text), (int.Parse(txtHeight.Text)));
    else
        img = image;

    //this is for situations, where the image is not read from disk, and is stored in the memort(e.g. image comes from a camera or snapshot)
    ImageFormat fmt = new ImageFormat(image.RawFormat.Guid);
    var imageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == image.RawFormat.Guid);
    if (imageCodecInfo == null)
    {
        fmt = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
    }

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(ms, fmt);
        byte[] image_byte_array = ms.ToArray();
        Classify_Image(image_byte_array, ms.Length, result, out len, top_n_results);
    }

    return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
}
```

By doing this after resizing the image from C#, we don't face any distortions at all.

I couldn't, however, figure out why the resize on OpenCV part wouldn't work as expected!

Comment: marvelous work! I can confirm that this still works three years later using a WPF app with a C++ dll using opencv 3.4.3

Comment: glad it made your day ;)