# Passing bitmap from C# to C++ via a struct

Tags: c#, c++

First, I've read the a few questions regarding this issue, the most helpful being:
[Passing bitmap from c# to c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463876/passing-bitmap-from-c-sharp-to-c)

I was unable to get the provided solutions to work as I kept getting an `AccessViolationException`.

What I'm attempting to do is pass bitmap data to an unmanaged c++ dll. To do this I created a struct which holds a pointer to the image data as well as its length. I'm using a struct as I plan on passing in multiple images (in a single call) to the unmanaged API.

What I implemented **works** but I have a feeling there is probably some serious drawbacks so I'm curious as to what those drawbacks could be.

My current solution uses a generic pointer to hold the image data. This of course would be a drawback as I lose type safety. Anyway here is the relevant code.

> c++ dll

**raw_image.h**

```
struct raw_image
{
   void* data;
   int size;
};
```

**alignment.cpp (exports)**

```
ALIGNMENT_API void submit( raw_image& img )
{
    cv::Mat mat = cv::imdecode( cv::_InputArray(
        static_cast<uchar*>( img.data ), img.size ), cv::IMREAD_COLOR );
    cv::imshow( "image", mat );
    cv::waitKey( );
    cv::destroyWindow( "image" );
}
```

> C# dll

**RawImage.cs**

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
internal unsafe struct RawImage
{
    internal void* ImageData;
    internal int Length;
}
```

**Aligner.cs (import)**

```
[DllImport( "alignment-vc141-mtd-x64.dll", CallingConvention = 
 CallingConvention.Cdecl )]
    static extern void submit( RawImage img );
```

And this is where I pass the image to the unmanaged API.

```
using( var bitmap = new Bitmap( "AlignmentCenter.jpg" ) )
using( var stream = new MemoryStream( ) )
{
    bitmap.Save( stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg );
    var source = stream.ToArray( );
    fixed( void* ptr = source )
    {
        var raw = new RawImage
        {
            ImageData = ptr,
            Length = source.Length
        };
        submit( raw );
     }
  }
```

Is what I'm doing unsafe? Am I copying more than I should? 
One last thing, I know about `EmguCv` and I've used it in the past but I won't be using it here.

Comment: If your code works, maybe you should ask your question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I think there you can get more accurate answer.

Comment: Since you have working code, this might be more on-topic at CodeReview. I'm not sure how the questions you've asked can be answered in a way that isn't simply opinion. Consider if you really just want a yes or no answer, or if you're looking for alternatives. This isn't really a yes or no answer sort of place.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Do you know if there is a quick way to migrate the question over to CodeReview? Or should I just close this question and cut and paste it over there manually?